# Regular expression: replace one character set with another

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string *( e.g. `3122323123123`)* and want to replace any `1->ax`, `2->by` and `3->cz`.

How do I do that in bash?

I started with the character set `[123]` and tried with "sed", but didn't know how to write the replacement expression ?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: I think it'd be easier to iterate over each character and convert the number into a character than using a regex.

Comment: If you are using PHP, this can be achieved without using regex like this: `$new_string = str_replace(array('1','2','3'), array('a','b','c'), '3122323123123');`

Comment: What tool or language are you using ?

Comment: Please note: Regex questions should **always** be tagged with the language that you're using as well as regex, because regular expression syntax and capabilities differ a lot from one language to another. Having said all that, I don't think you need regex here; this looks like a job for a simple `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not the tool for you here. There's nothing in your question that requires any regex.

You didn't specify your language, but if you're working in PHP, you could use the function [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) which does exactly what you are looking for.

And good old `str_replace()` can probably also do what you want too, as it can accept arrays for the search/replacement arguments.

Most other languages should have similar capabilities that mean you shouldn't need regex for this.

Answer (score 3):

Look at standard [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) utility.

```
% echo "3122323123123" | tr "123" "abc" 
cabbcbcabcabc
```

If you want to replace a character with multiple characters, you can use sed for every replacement:

```
% echo "3122323123123" | sed -e "s/1/ax/g" -e "s/2/by/g" -e "s/3/cz/g"
czaxbybyczbyczaxbyczaxbycz
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about this one. I used `tr` from Perl.

Comment: Note: It's also super useful for deleting specified characters with `-d` option.

Comment: Okey but if I want to replace a character with a string like "1"->"ax", "2"->"by" and "3"->"cz", how do I do that? I thought that the command sed would solve this

Comment: In that case, you can replace one by one using `sed`, as you said. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In c#

```
string input = "3122323123123";
string output = intput.Replace('1','a').Replace('2','b').Replace('3','c');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for example:

```
$ echo "3122323123123" | perl -pe "tr/123/abc/"    
cabbcbcabcabc
```